# "se prendre en main(s)": Singular or Plural?

Tags: expressions, pluriel

I just said in conversation:

> Tant que tu n’arrêtes pas avec ton laxisme, elle ne va pas **se prendre en mains** de sitôt.

I wanted to express the idea of "growing up and taking her life into her own hands", and I wonder if "mains" should have been in the singular instead:

> Tant que tu n’arrêtes pas avec ton laxisme, elle ne va pas **se prendre en main** de sitôt.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/main/48688/locution?q=destin), *se prendre en main* should stay in singular:

> Prendre en **main** quelque chose, quelqu'un,
>   s'en occuper pour redresser une situation.

Answer (score 3):

[*Le bon usage*](http://www.lebonusage.com/) indique :

> Théoriquement, on choisit ***en main*** ou *en mains* selon qu’il s’agit d’une seule main ou des deux. Mais, dans la pratique, cette distinction est de peu d’intérêt. [La version 2000 du dictionnaire de] *L’Académie* admet aussi le pluriel dans *Je lui ai remis votre lettre en MAIN propre* ([*main, I, 2*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/main)). Au sens figuré, le singulier paraît l’emporter dans des expressions comme *prendre EN MAIN les intérêts de quelqu’un, avoir la preuve EN MAIN,* etc. ; — le pluriel dans *en bonnes mains, en mauvaises mains, en mains sûres.*

*Le Petit Robert* indique lui aussi *prendre en main(s)* dans le sens de prendre en charge, mentionnant que l’expression date de la fin du XIIe siècle, ce qui lui confère donc un vénérable huit cents et quelques années d’existence.

Quelques autres sources n’indiquent que le singulier, mais ne se prononcent pas du tout sur le pluriel, se contentant de ne pas le mentionner : *Larousse, le Dictionnaire d’expressions et locutions* de *Robert*.

À chacun de voir pour soi, donc, si l’on se prend en charge à une ou à deux mains. On peut toutefois noter que dans l’usage autant que dans les outils linguistiques, la prise en charge à une main semble plus populaire¹.

---

¹ <sub>*Je laisse à chacun le soin de tirer ses conclusions sur cette troublante statistique.*</sub>